# Как пропустить определенный индекс в for-loop Javascript

Tags: javascript, массивы

Как можно перепрыгнуть определенный индекс в цикле? 
Например, дан код

```
var a = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var b = ['a', 'd', 'b', 'c'];

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  if (a[i] === b[i]) {
    alert('ok');
  }
}
```

Как я могу задать условие — если `i=1 (b)` — перейти к следующему, то есть `i=i+1`

PS. Например, если надо пропустить `0` индекс, можно начать отсчет с `1`

```
for (var i = 1; i < a.length; i++)
```

Если не нужен последний индекс, то

```
for (var i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++)
```

Как не учитывать индекс, если он не первый и не последний?

Answer (score 4):

Для этого предназначен оператор [continue](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue)

```js
const a = ['a','b','c'];
for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i ++) {
  if (i === 1) continue;
  console.log(i, a[i]);
}
```

Для выхода из цикла можно использовать оператор [break](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break)

```js
const a = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];
for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i ++) {
  if (i === 1) continue;
  if (i === 4) break;
  console.log(i, a[i]);
}
```

Comment: Может лучше ссылки на [`MDN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue) давать?

Comment: Я думаю, что лучше давать ссылки в гугл. но сообщество не одобряет(